# In jenkins how can I see last time build ran, by his xml file?

Tags: jenkins

I Have more than 1000 jobs in Jenkins,
And I would like to go through all of them in order to clean unused jobs.
What is the recommended way to do so?

I guess in every job "xml" file there is an indication to when it last ran,
Can anyone point me where this file is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up filter the jobs by the "**View job Filters**" plugin,

You can use **"Filter by Build Trend"** option as follows:

Create a view for "All jobs" -> go to edit view -> in "add job filter " choose "Build Trend Filter"  -> choose the filter you desire.

This is what I did:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in one step. But you can do this in 2 steps.

1. Find the URLs of all jobs with this:

   https://jenkins-server/api/json?tree=jobs[url]
2. Get more info about each job by using the urls returned from step 1:

   url-from-step1/api/json

This will give you the healthreport, last failed/successful build etc. If you need more info about these builds you can make a new request with :

```
url-from-step1/last-build-number/api/json
```

I recommend using JSON, and using JQ (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/, https://jqplay.org/) to parse your JSON

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). The following urls might be relevant for you:

- *https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/api/xml?tree=jobs[name]* -- to get a list of jobs
- *https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/job/{jobName}/lastBuild/buildTimestamp?format=yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss* -- to get the time of last build of job *{jobName}*

Feel free to change xml to json/python...

I can provide a following shell script as a rough example:

```
#!/bin/bash

jenkinsUrlBase='https://ci.jenkins-ci.org'

callJenkins() {
    curl --silent --show-error -g "$jenkinsUrlBase${1}"
}

callJenkins '/api/xml?tree=jobs[name]' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//hudson/job/name' | while read projectName ; do
        timestamp=$(callJenkins "/job/${projectName}/lastBuild/buildTimestamp?format=yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")
        echo "Last build of ${projectName}: ${timestamp}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit directory and file structure in ${JENKINS_HOME}:

```
cd ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds
ls -lt | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'
```

Example output:

```
2015-08-13_11-48-25
```